# Eclipse: LD_LIBRARY_PATH, OpenJDK and libjpeg

Tags: eclipse, ld, java, libjpeg

On my development machine (Linux) I have not set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all, as the libraries I'm using are either in default directories or I've added them to `ld.conf`.

But when I'm using Eclipse, my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to:

```
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/client:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386:
/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.2.17:
/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.2.17"
```

(added line breaks for readability).

I don't mind xulrunner ones, but the OpenJDK causes my apps to load

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/libjpeg.so
```

instead of

```
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so
```

Which lead to subsequent fail, as the one from OpenJDK is 6b, while I'm using libjpeg 8.

I know I can override `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` while compiling C++, but it fails as soon as I try to execute Python code linking the shared libraries I've just compiled.

How can I change this global `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come to mind:

1. Remove libjpeg6b from the system and
   hope that OpenJDK will be happy with
   libjpeg8
2. Recompile OpenJDK against
   libjpeg8

Comment: +1 for 1. suggestion, although not yet accepting that as an answer, because first, I'm not sure it it'll not break something else, secondly it isn't really an answer to the question, although helps with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you launching the Python from eclipse?  You can set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the *Run Configurations>Environment* tab, so it overrides whatever you see as the default one.

Comment: +1, as it's also valid suggestion. Problem with it, is that it's not global. Have to repeat this for each configuration.